# Dialogflow: How do i use an intent like a function?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have an intent which reads the user_id. When the user asks for his history or new test i want to use the same intent user_id to get his ID.
As far as i have understood when i use multiple input contexts all of them need to be satisfied.
How would i go about doing this?

Edit: I am a beginner so i dont know if this is the right way to do it but it seems to work

```
function customerIDHandler(agent){
    if(agent.getContext('view-history') !== null){

    }else if(agent.getContext('test-menu') !== null){

    }       
}
```

where view-history and test-menu are two output context used just to show which path i came from to this intent

Answer (score 0):

You don't need one Context per ID, you just need a Context to store the ID in the parameters. In the Intent where they express their ID, set an Outgoing Context and it will store the ID as a parameter. Then, in future Intents, you can use this parameter from the Context in your fulfillment.

Comment: This is correct. Watch out for Context lifespan, though - if your conversation chain is long, be sure to either 1) set the lifespan to a high number when you create it or 2) reset the lifespan on every subsequent conversation step (intent)